Проблема подключения пользователей к комнате socketio (websocket)
Не так давно я понял, что мне нужно внедрить вебсокет в свой проект, чтобы была синхронизация для всех возможных пользователей. Решил использовать Socket.io для этого.
Конкретную задачу, которую мне нудно решить с помощью вебсокета - это синхронизация таймера у всех пользователей. Меня не устроило изначально, что при каждом новом подключении создается свой socket.id, получается, что каждый в своем мире.
Захотел исправить ситуацию с помощью комнаты, чтобы была единая комната и все к ней подключались, комнату решил сделать просто из url. Все подготовил, но почему-то не работает.
В логах выводится socket.id при подключении, но логи с подключением к комнате не выводятся, ну и соответственно код ниже тоже не отрабатывает логики(таймер).
Перепробовал множество подходов, ничего не помогает. Какая проблема в моем коде?(заранее признаю, что профан в веб-сокетах, только начал изучение)
index.js
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5050;
const userRouter = require('./routes/user.routes');
const gameRouter = require('./routes/game.routes');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { startTimer, getTimerValue, stopTimer } = require('./socket');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  }
});

// const joinRoom = (socket, room) => {
//   socket.join(room);
//   socket.emit('message', `welcome to  ${room}!`);
// }
const joinRoom = (socket, room) => {
  socket.join(room);
  io.to(room).emit('message', `Добро пожаловать в комнату ${room}!`);
}



io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Новое подключение', socket.id);

    socket.on('join', (room) => {
      joinRoom(socket, room);
    })
  

  
  socket.on('startTimer', (timerValue) => {
    startTimer(socket, timerValue);
  });
  
  socket.on('timer:update', (timerValue)=>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('timer:update', timerValue);
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Сокет отключен', socket.id);
    
  });

});




const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  methods: "*",
  allowedHeaders: "*"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));



app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use('/api', userRouter);
    app.use('/game', gameRouter);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Cтарутем на порту ${PORT}`));

socket.js(timer)
let timerValue = 0;
let timerInterval;

const startTimer = (socket, initialTimerValue) => {
    timerValue = initialTimerValue;

    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timerValue--;
        socket.emit('timer:update', timerValue);
        if (timerValue === 0) {
            clearInterval(timerInterval);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

const getTimerValue = () => {
    return timerValue;
};

const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
};

module.exports = { startTimer, getTimerValue, stopTimer };

часть кода react.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"; 
import './FirstGame.css'
import Timer from '../components/Timer.jsx'
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

const FirstGame = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(361);
    const [resultNumber, setResultNumber] = React.useState(null);
    const [countdown, setCountdown] = React.useState(11);
 
    const itemsPerPage = 10;
    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
    const currentItems = lastResult.slice().reverse().slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
    const latestNumber = gameHistory.length > 0 ? gameHistory[gameHistory.length - 1].number : null;
    const color = gameHistory.length > 0 ? gameHistory[gameHistory.length - 1].color : null;



    const startCountdown = () => {
        let timer = 11;
        const timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
          timer--;
          setCountdown(timer);
          if (timer === 0) {
            clearInterval(timerInterval);
          }
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
          clearInterval(timerInterval);
        };
        
      };
    
    
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    let room = localStorage.getItem('room');
    if (!room) {
        room = pathname.slice(1);
        localStorage.setItem('room', room);
    }
      

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:5050');

    
    
    
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Соединение установлено", socket.id);
    });
    
    socket.emit('join', room);
    socket.on('message', () => {
        console.log('Подключение к комнате:', room);
    })  
    

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Соединение разорвано с сокетом", socket.id);
      
    });

    

    socket.on("timer:update", (timerValue) => {
      setCountdown(timerValue);
    })

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };

  }, [room]);
    


Ну для начала перенесите socket.emit('join', room); в событие socket.on("connect",, т.к. emit может сработать до установки соединения

Да, в курсе этого, изначально так  и было. Перед тем как задать вопрос, пробывал все способы и оставил так. Но к сожалению не меняет ситуации..

Ну тогда только дебаг. Открывайте вкладу сеть и смотрите, какие запросы отправляются с клиента. Обложит все ваши события console.log(), что бы было понятно, что где и как вызывается и с какими параметрами. Так же попробуйт другие события присылать а сервер и смотреть, как он будет реагировать.

Вот сейчас продолжаю тестировать, чтобы найти ошибку, извините, может глупый вопрос, а в chromeDevTools -> network у сокета должно состояние быть "выполнено"? Просто только сейчас заметил, что у меня нет состояния, в время зависло в "ожидание"

Все правильно, т.к. сокет ждет сообщений от сервера. И вот если на него ткнуть, то можно видеть, какие сообщения уходят, какие приходят
